# How can I alter a gem on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, rubygems

I recently deployed my app to heroku.  It uses Devise, which I had to alter the after_sign_up_path so it would redirect correctly to a set page after someone signs up.  This works fine locally, but when I deploy on heroku it installs the original unmodified devise gem.

Does anyone know of a way to modify a gem on heroku, or to make it use the modified gem in my vendor folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in general, it shouldn't be any different deploying your app on heroku than anywhere else.

One difference is that on heroku you're probably running in 'production' environment settings, and locally in 'development'.  You can run in production locally too, if that were the issue.

But I don't think it is. When you say you "altered" Devise, do you mean you actually edited the source code inside the Devise gem source itself?

That's not a good practice. When a new version of Devise comes out, perhaps with security patches, what are you going to do?  Re-customize the new version? It's not a great maintenance plan. If you really want to do this you can. The best way might be to create a fork of the Devise gem in a git repo (on github or anywhere else), customize that and commit your customizations to the repo, and then point to your customized version of Devise from your own git repo in your Gemfile with `gem 'devise', :git => 'http://some.git.repo.clone.url.org'`

But it's a bad idea.

Devise probably already supports your use case with configuration, rather than by editing Devise source code. Most experienced devs would consider that a much preferable way to accomplish what you want.

In this case, it looks like you should be providing an `after_signup_path` method override in your own local app, not modifying the default implementation in devise source.  Google for more info, or consult [the URL Finks provides in another answer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out), or post another question specifically asking how to do what you want to do with devise (it's actually nothing to do with heroku), being as specific as possible about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'd suggest you remove the part about development/production as it's not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: I think it's relevant because it's one of the most common reasons, I think, for newbies to have a problem with "it doesn't work on heroku but does work on my local machine."  I don't _think_ that's what's happening with the OP, but his description was a bit vague, so I could be wrong, and other people coming to this question later as "how can I alter a gem on heroku" may find it useful to be tipped to the dev/production issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you forked Devise to your github account, you can point your Gemfile to it by doing this:

```
gem "devise", :git => "git://github.com/user/devise.git", :branch => "my-awesome-branch"
```

By the way, I'd recommend you overwrite some devise methods rather than hack the gem but thats just my 2cents.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question but according to devise wiki, you don't have to alter the gem to get the redirect behavior you like, you just need to override the `after_sign_in_path_for` method in application controller. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out

Example:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user_path
end
```

Comment: Okay, I read this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29 and it seemed to want me to modify the registrations controller in devise.

Comment: acutally I read it wrong...it says to make your own registrations controller.  Oops.